# One word for highly frustrated/hopeless

Tags: word-request, synonyms

Is there a stronger word for "highly frustrated" or "feeling very hopeless"?
So If I want to tell someone that I am highly frustrated by the work I am doing or convey that it's very demotivating, what are the alternative words I can use there?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried looking up alternatives in a Thesaurus?  [such as this one](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/frustrated)

Comment: I'd say "disillusioned" but I don't have the reputation to post. I think frustration usually happens as a result of having high expectations, and being let down. If you had low expectations to start with, you wouldn't feel frustrated. So I would use "disillusioned" to convey that you had high expectations but were let down, frustrated, and feel hopeless.

Answer (score 8):

You could try “despondent”:

> Adjective: despondent (comparative more despondent, superlative most
> despondent)
>
> In low spirits from loss of hope or courage.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/despondent

Answer (score 7):

[Disheartened](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/disheartened)

> no longer confident or enthusiastic about something

[Wordhippo.com](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/disheartened.html) has various synonyms for disheartened to convey

> Having lost determination or confidence
>
> Feeling angry or annoyed
>
> Suffering from frustration or dissatisfaction

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest "exasperated" as a synonym for *very frustrated* and maybe "soul-sucking" to describe *work that is very demotivating*.

References:
List of synonyms for 'very frustrating':
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/most%20frustrating

For 'soul-sucking':  (the link is to someone's blog, which illustrates the phrase being used in context)
https://btr.michaelkwan.com/2017/12/01/soul-sucking-habits/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are "at wit's end":

> The limit of one's sanity or mental capacity; the point of desperation.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wits%27_end

Answer (score 1):

The work you're asking me to do is very **demoralizing**

Answer (score 0):

*Wiktionary* gives "**despairing**",
meaning "Feeling, expressing, or caused by despair; hopeless."

Comment: Desperate is better than despairing.